# Can I download a Google sheet cell as a JS file?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, download

If my Google sheet looks like:

```
    A           B               C                               D
1   Template    {content}       document.write('{content}')
2
3   Name        Value           Output                          Button
4   Test        A test          =SUBSTITUTE(c$1, b$1, B4)       [A button with a custom function...]
5   Dummy       Just a dummy    =SUBSTITUTE(c$1, b$1, B5)       [A button with a custom function...]
6   Foo         Foo this        =SUBSTITUTE(c$1, b$1, B6)       [A button with a custom function...]
7   Bar         Bar that        =SUBSTITUTE(c$1, b$1, B7)       [A button with a custom function...]
```

Can I use a custom function that will make each button download its related cells as a JS file? For example, clicking D4 should save C4 as {A4}.js (i.e. Test.js), so that Test.js will contain:

```
document.write('A test')
```

Comment: Yes, you can write a script that creates a file with arbitrary content and serves it. You wouldn't want to use buttons though, soccer they take no arguments. (This is a really broad question as there are numerous ways to do this.)

Comment: Any alternative to buttons? It's important the script will know which button was clicked, so that it'll know which cells' values to take. And any examples to the numerous ways you've mentioned will be appreciated.

Comment: I would use either a menu or sidebar script (that references the active cell). Unless you want to write a script for each button and name them all differently, and hope that no rows are added or deleted or buttons moved.

Comment: That can work. Do you have any examples of creating a file with arbitrary content?

Comment: Search `DriveApp.createFile()` or  something like that.